# How to create a method with a spark.broadcast[Map] as parameter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know this question looks silly at first, but please look at the code.

I created a broadcasted map this way :

```
val rdd = sqlc
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .options(Map("url" -> driver, "dbtable" -> clientsTable))
  .load()
  .select("client_name","client_age")
  .map { data => (data.getString(0),data.getInt(1)) }
  .collectAsMap()

val clients = sqlc.sparkContext.broadcast(rdd)
```

The I create a method with `value` as parameter :

```
def doSomething(clients: Broadcast[Map[String,Int]]) clients.toString()
```

But, when I call this method in my code,Scala IDE throws this error :

```
type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[scala.collection.Map[String,Int]] required: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] Note: scala.collection.Map[String,Int] >: Map[String,Int], but class Broadcast is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

I can't find what is wrong here, even changing the method signature with a silly `scala.collection.immutable.Map` doesn't work... The compiler gives me the same error.

FYI : I am using scala 2.10 and scala IDE 4.3.0

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap` returns a `scala.collection.Map`, so your function's signature should match this type, and not the more-specific `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, which is the default when you just write `Map`:

```
def doSomething(clients: Broadcast[scala.collection.Map[String,Int]])
```